# Would these changes to humanity due to genetic memory help technology develop more quickly or slowly than our world?

Tags: society, religion

There is a long running video game series called assassin's creed that uses a concept of accessing genetic memories of an individual. A machine called the animus allows a person to relive the lives of their ancestors as if they were actually there. You would see the past through their eyes and thoughts. The purpose of this was to gain lost knowledge for historical reasons. Only certain people were shown to be capable of using this device.

Suppose humanity as a whole had the ability to access the genetic memories of their ancestors. This ability would be passed down from their mother, and would only contain memories of her direct ancestral line (mother, grandmother, great grandmother, etc). This ability could be used by anyone with a certain amount of training, but some would be more skilled than others. The further back the person lived, the more difficult it would be to access. This has led to the mainstream religion that revolves around honoring ancestors and an adherence to social tradition.

Given these changes to humanity, I would think that inheritance would be matrilineal and society would be broken up into clans. Mothers may be at the center of the household. A culture would develop in which ancestors are venerated and there would be strong emphasis on social tradition. "This has been the way it has always been done" would be common logic. Would this setup hinder progress and innovation in society? Will technological advancement suffer? How would it affect institutions like democracy?

Comment: I think this is speculative and not really answereable/too broad. By a set of varying paramters I can get you virtually any answer. Maybe women are opressed and have to study all their life so their sons can access that knowledge? See, just some social parameter changed your whole set of assumptions. It's the same with asking what would happen. Maybe nothing, maybe anything.

Comment: @DonQuiKong please visit meta, question sandbox.

Comment: 'Reliving lives' seems a particularly slow and annoying method of 'accessing memories'. The actual useful data transfer would be rather low without some way of summarizing (like writing).

Comment: Seems like 'honoring ancestors' would the the *opposite* of knowing that your great-grandparents were just as horny and drunken and shallow and flawed as their descendant.

Comment: WIth the existence of genetic memory, I think we may need to have a *very* precise definition of "technological advancement."  That sort of ability is a real game changer, not just for technology, but for absolutely every single facet of society in its entirety.  It may be that the thing you and I call technology simply doesn't exist and something else exists that is almost-but-not-quite-technology.  If anything, you might be able to write a whole book series, like *Dune* (which actually addresses this exact topic)

Comment: @Molot so it has been asked in the sandbox, but it's still too broad :S. I really don't see how this could be answered without a very strict set of rules. Accessing memories is probably a mess. I don't even see where it is better than just learning as we do without a way of separating the standard day memories from the important ones containing wisdom and knowledge. Hell, without an index, that's probably just going to lead to adolescents searching for memories of sex and a family owned book of the few actually important memories. And it would put **a lot** of pressure on women to behave ...

Comment: Unfortunately voting to close, because this is _really_ interesting to think about. Societies would be matriarchal, and men would be considered essentially disposable (memory dead-end, so who cares if they die?) The "family line" also got more strictly enforced. It's not just "good breeding", but the knowledge associated with the family line. Family lines would get _very_ specialized. Imagine a sword fighter who's essentially been training for _centuries_. Youngest children would also be more highly prized (more memories), and women past childbearing would have the same status as men.

Comment: Insufficiently constrained / poorly thought out. VTC

Comment: @Azuaron or as I said the exact opposite and women are used to breed memories for men. And training from watching memories? depends on how vivid they are and if you have them or can just watch them etc.

Comment: Progress would likely grind to a halt as old ideas and norm can't really die out. the earlier in life the memories become available the less society will be able to change. On the other hand gender equality should be easier since people will remember life from as many males as female ancestors.

Comment: @DonQuiKong The "most desirable" women are going to be the ones with the best memories to draw from, which means those memories have to be cultivated, and the best memories are going to come from real experience. It would be really difficult to get women with "the best" memories without also giving them the appropriate power to engage in the most powerful experiences. The highest level positions (government, corporate, etc.) might even be _denied_ to people who couldn't pass on their memories (men, infertile, post-childbearing) because it would be considered a loss for future generations.